# Can I legally remove my mask once my train cross the Italian-Swiss border?

Tags: trains, covid-19, italy, borders, switzerland

Currently Italy has a mask mandate inside long distance trains. I am to take a train from Italy to Switzerland, where masks are not mandatory anywhere.

Once the train crosses the border into Switzerland, can I legally remove my mask?

Comment: If in doubt, ask the conductor or just see what everybody else is doing. Wearing a mask is always the safest choice in a train

Comment: Probably depends on the train, its operator, the staff on board…

Comment: You can certainly do it after you pass the first Swiss station.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean can you legally remove your mask?

Comment: No train operator in Switzerland currently requires you to wear a mask.

Comment: @Turkeyphant That sounds fairly obvious. Or do you think that OP could have been asking us whether they are physically capable of removing their mask?

Comment: I don't like to assume anything. And whether an action is "legal" or not is also often ill-defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the train is in Switzerland the Swiss rules apply. There is not a single train operator in Switzerland that requires masks. So you can remove your mask once in Switzerland.

Comment: This turned out to be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just because there is not a government mandate to mask doesn't necessarily mean that the train operator doesn't have their own rules. For example, Trenitalia [currently says](https://www.trenitalia.com/it/informazioni/linee-guida-per-viaggiare/indicazioni-per-viaggiare.html) (Google Translate): "Its necessary to wear an FFP2 type mask to protect the nose and mouth for the duration of the trip". The best way to find out for sure would be to ask the conductor about it - they'll know the latest rules and regulations aboard their own train.

That being said, Italy is [expected to lift](https://www.thelocal.it/20220414/italy-to-decide-on-lifting-covid-mask-mandate-after-easter/) their masking rules by May, so this question should cease to be relevant as masking will become voluntary in both nations.

Comment: Trenitalia operates not a single train in Switzerland, so their rules do not apply.